# Load first page on splashscreen using phonegap on android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, splash-screen

Hi i'm using phonegap in conjunction with Jquery mobile. I'm trying to immediately fetch the main page, while showing the user a splashscreen.

In PhoneGap for Android i'm using this

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 2000);
```

While this loads the splash, it also delays the loading of index.html. It it possible to start fetching it right away? Also, if not with phonegap, has anybody done this using JQM instead of phonegap?

UPDATE: After using it with a slower loading first page (doing a json request) it kinda looks like the splash screens shows for a longer period of time, so this appears to be the default behavior

Comment: i dont think loading it right away is possible :(

Comment: mmm, that's a shame. I'll look into doing it with JQM. Maybe they have an easy way to load a splash screen as well, but I was hoping somebody has already done this

Comment: hi, I'm struggling with the same problem... trying to show android's native build splash screen while it prefetches the phonegap + JQM multipage index.html. Have you found a solution? Any help / experiences are appriciated. I would like to get rid of the "3 seconds black screen" appearing after my android-splash.

Answer (score 1):

As given [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html), you could kill the splashscreen once you have loaded all the assets and DOM elements have been loaded.

something like this: 
Java:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen",R.drawable.splashscreen);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 2000);
```

on your HTML, javascript section:

```
function onDeviceReady() 
            {
                cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
                window.MacAddress = new MacAddress();
                window.MacAddress.getMacAddress(function(result){
                    database._mac_address = result.mac;
                }, function(){
                    database._mac_address = '01:02:03:04:05:06';
                });  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implement better solution.
You can set your custom splashscreen and hide it with JS call after page have been loaded

https://github.com/inetstd/phonegap-android-custom-splashscreen/wiki